# Pandas resampling by day which not start at 00:00

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to resample my dataframe by day, so i easily get my df resample by day but the day start at 00:00 and stop at midnight like a normal day.

```
my_df.resample('D', label="left" ).sum()
```

So i got the sum of all my previous result by day, but my question is, with pandas 0.3, is it possible to change the start of the day at 06:00 and the end at 6:00 when i resampling?

Thanks,

Comment: `resample` has a [`offset`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) option.

Comment: Yes, i saw this but the doc is not really good, i add base=6 but not worked

Comment: should be: `offset='6H'`.

Comment: Ok i added base=6 but this not work if rule = '1D' but work if rule='24H'
Thanks for your help !